# US Foreign Aid Accountability

Tags: united-states, international-relations, foreign-policy

When the United States gives money to foreign countries for some stated purpose, who checks to see that the money we give them actually goes to where it was intended? Also does this supposed audit of U.S. aid ever get published in any documents accessible to the general public?

Comment: This is 2 different questions. Does the money get delivered and used for its stated purpose? AND Does the money go where it was intended to go? Yes, the money goes exactly where it was intended to go...the corrupt leaders of those countries we are trying to buy off. The little that is left then gets siphoned by unscrupulous aid organization leaders. You can find thousands of web pages of information covering this topic by googling simple related search terms, such as "where does foreign aid money end up". Improve the question by stating some of what you found and want to know is true or not.

Comment: @Dunk You are reading too much into the question. It's a simple question: Who is responsible for checking where the money end up, and are those audits publicly accessible? That's it, a simple and straightforward question looking for an equally straightforward answer. Either there's an office or organization that is responsible for such audits or there is not. And if there is, either they publicise the audits or they do not. Let's keep the discussion to a minimum please, the goal of the site is to provide answers.

Comment: @YannisRizos: You are correct, I hope to get a good answer here but I'm not betting the farm on it!

Comment: To give a simple answer to your question the answer is that the Inspector General is responsible for this oversight. However, once again, a simple search will reveal that even they admit that they are incapable of accounting for money that is given to foreign governments because they don't get the necessary cooperation. Google "U.S. Foreign Assistance: What oversight Mechanisms are in place to ensure accountability". This was a just released report, which basically says, we were told millions went here, millions went there... but when we look, it isn't anywhere.

Comment: @Dunk: Thats what I thought: shoudn't we be demanding of foreign countries to have mechanisms of oversight in place BEFORE we give them any money? Isn't that what all those "geniuses" who go to Harvard and Yale ( dont take this personally if I did not mention your university) and then get jobs in government figure out how to implement ?

Comment: @William:Think about it. If you were the leader(s) of another country, would you want to report the details of your business to another country? What about your political opponents? They could easily paint you as a puppet. Also, if these countries had sufficient mechanisms of oversight then they probably wouldn't be in a position to need the aid. Unless, that aid is intended to carry out our business for us, without us being directly linked. That case doesn't put us in much of a position to make demands, either.

Comment: @Dunk: Ah ha Mr. Dunk, I have snared you into my lair! Here is the rub : if the U.S. is really a "democracy" then the people in Govment (thank you Damon Wayens) are supposed to act according to the will of the people , right? If you were to poll the people of the U.S. about whether or not we should give a foreign govement your hard earned cash, what would be the likelyhood that any American taxpayer would go along with it, assuming that the aid is NOT for some immediate humanitarian relief?

Comment: @Dunk If you have an answer to the question, please _post an answer_. Comments are not meant to be used for answers, they are only meant for clarifying the question or to offer constructive criticism.

Comment: @Yannis:If I had the time to provide a sufficient answer with good references then I would. In the mean time comments (based on what I have read/watched/heard in the past) have to suffice since my memory is not good enough to remember the exact places I learned these things to provide references. Maybe my comments will give someone else the urge to prove me wrong/right or to get them on a train of thought to provide a sufficient answer to the original question.

Comment: @William-Lucky for me your lair has a back exit. You make the completely wrong assumption that "the people" are informed or even care. Also there's different ways to ask your question "Do you believe america should donate a billion dollars for humanitarian aid?" Will give a completely different response to your poll than "Do you believe america should donate a billion dollars towards humanitarian aid if you knew that only $100 million will actually get to its intended destination and the other $900 million will be towards government graft?"

Comment: @DunK: I never said that I thought the "people" were informed or that they cared, (they obviously don't). You read too much into my comment!

Comment: @William:Well your claims "after I was snared in your lair" would require probably both conditions, but at least one or the other in order to be valid claims. While theoretically, the government is supposed to act according to the will of the people, it certainly doesn't. And this is on most issues, not just foreign aid. Yet, the people either don't care or are too ignorant to even know this isn't happening. Also, most people don't want their money going to foreign countries even for humanitarian reasons, but that's the most effort they are willing to put into that topic.

Comment: @Dunk: Kidding about the lair thing :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First what are the [types of foreign aid](http://www.intelligenteconomist.com/types-of-foreign-aid/), otherwise known as Official Development Assistance:**

- Bilateral aid – when the capital flows from a developed nation to a developing nation
- Multilateral aid – when the capital flows to developing nations from a world agency such as the World Bank
- Military aid/humanitarian aid-security and narcotics aid, emergency assistance in response to natural disasters, food aid.

**How does the US fund these types of foreign aid:**
20 US government agencies administered US foreign assistance activities through bilateral and multilateral channels to over 150 countries with greater sums going to wealthier developing nations. US Agency for International Development (USAID) and the State Department manage the bulk of assistance programs. The Department of Defense and the US Department of Agriculture manage a large number of programs as well.

**Who is responsible for oversight?**
Each individual agency is responsible for the oversight of its program. Foreign aid is not a department of the federal government, so there is no one in charge of overseeing its efficiency as a unique program or goal.

**How should the public get information how well foreign aid is operating over-all**
The [Center for Global Development](http://www.cgdev.org/topics/aid_effectiveness) is working on ground breaking projects to improve aid effectiveness. They have created an aid quality scale, an aid dashboard, and an interactive aid map to prevent redundancy of programs. Otherwise, at this time, the best thing to do is to research programs at the largest foreign aid providers, such as USAID and the World Bank. Each will have public documents. For example, here is information on recent audits by the Inspector General at [USAID](http://oig.usaid.gov/).